# Java unmodifiableMap can be replaced with 'Map.copyOf' call

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and I recently learnt that somtimes it's important to deepcopy a Collection and make an unmodifiable view of it so that the data inside remains safe and unchanged.
When I try to practice this(unmodifiableMap2), I get a warning from IDEA that

> unmodifiableMap Can be replaced with 'Map.copyOf' call

That's weird for me because I think unmodifiableMap is not only a copy of the underlying map. Besides, when I try to create the same unmodifiableMap in another way(unmodifiableMap1), the warning doesn't pop up!

How should I understand this behavior of IDEA ?

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(1,1);
        map.put(2,2);

        Map<Integer, Integer> map1 = new HashMap<>(map);

        Map<Integer, Integer> unmodifiableMap1 = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map1);

        Map<Integer, Integer> unmodifiableMap2 = Collections.unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<>(map););

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: *That's wired for me because I think unmodifiableMap is not only a copy of the underlying map.* - yes it is only a shallow copy with blocked write operations.

Comment: Well, `Integer`s are immutable, they don't need to be copied.  And `map` is a local variable.  Those are safe if they are indeed entirely local, so your IDE might be taking that into consideration.  Overall though I think the intent here is more important than saving a few lines of code.  Do what makes the most sense, as long as it is correct.

Comment: `new HashMap<>(map)` does a copy.  `Collections.unmodifiableMap` makes it unmodifiable.  `Maps.copyOf` makes an unmodifiable copy.  So you could replace both, but not just one.

Comment: @Antoniossss – No, `unmodifiableMap` does *not* return a copy of the argument map, it just wraps it with an instance of a class that delegates all non-modifying methods of `Map` to those of the argument, all modifying methods will throw an exeption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An unmodifiable map using an existing reference to a map is perfectly fine, and there are many reasons you might want to do this.

Consider this class:

```
class Foo {
    private final Map<String, String> fooMap = new HashMap<>();

    // some methods which mutate the map

    public Map<String, String> getMap() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(fooMap);
    }
}
```

What this class does is provide a read-only view of the map it encapsulates. The class can be sure that clients who consume the map cannot alter it, they can just see its contents. They will also be able to see any updates to the entries if they keep hold of the reference for some time.

If we had tried to expose a read-only view by copying the map, it would take time and memory to perform the copy and the client would not see any changes because both maps are then distinct instances - the source and the copy.

However in the case of this:

```
Collections.unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<>(map));
```

You are first copying the map into a new hash map and then passing that copy into `Collections.unmodifiableMap`. The result is *effectively constant*. You do not have a reference to the copy you created with `new HashMap<>(map)`, and nor can you get one*.

If what you want is a constant map, then `Map.copyOf` is a more concise way of achieving that, so IntelliJ suggests you should use that instead.

In the first case, since the reference to the map already exists, IntelliJ cannot make the same inference about your intent so it gives no such suggestion.

You can see [the IntelliJ ticket for this feature](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-187212?_ga=2.82436630.186938826.1610314988-1457414669.1610314988) if you like, though it doesn't explain why the two are essentially equivalent, just that they are.

---

* well, you probably could via reflection, but IntelliJ is assuming that you won't

Comment: `An unmodifiable map using an existing reference to a map is perfectly fine,` With the proviso that if the original map can be (or is) modified, the unmodifiable one will reflect the changes, which might not be what you want.  (But also might be what you want, so it depends on requirements.  *Syntactically* and *semantically* it is fine, yes.)

Answer (score 7):

[`Map.copyOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#copyOf(java.util.Map)) makes a *copy* of the given `Map` instance, but it requires that no value in the map is `null`. Usually, this is the case, but it is not a strict requirement for a `Map` in general.

[`java.util.Collections.unmodifiableMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap(java.util.Map)) just wraps a reference to the given `Map` instance. This means that the receiver is unable to modify the map, but modifications to the original map (that one that was the argument to `unmodifiableMap()`) are visible to the receiver.

Assuming we have two threads, one iterates over the unmodifiable map, while the other modifies the original one. As a result, you may get a `ConcurrentModificationException` for an operation on the unmodifiable map … not funny to debug that thing!

This cannot happen with the copy created by `Map.copyOf()`. But this has a price: with a copy, you need two times the amount of memory for the map (roughly). For really large maps, this may cause memory shortages up to an `OutOfMemoryError`. Also not fun to debug!

In addition, just wrapping the existing map is presumably *much* faster than copying it.

So there is no *best* solution in general, but for most scenarios, I have a preference for using `Map.copyOf()` when I need an unmodifiable map.

---

The sample in the question did not wrap the *original* `Map` instance, but it makes a copy before wrapping it (either in a line of its own, or on the fly). This eliminates the potential problem with the 'under-the-hood' modification, but may bring the memory issue.

From my experience so far, `Map.copyOf( map )` looks to be more efficient than `Collections.unmodifiableMap( new HashMap( map ) )`.

---

By the way: `Map.copyOf()` returns a map that resembles a `HashMap`; when you copy a `TreeMap` with it, the sort order gets lost, while the wrapping with `unmodifiableMap()` keeps the underlying `Map` implementation and therefore also the sort order. So when this is important, you can use `Collections.unmodifiableMap( new TreeMap( map ) )`, while `Map.copyOf()` does not work here.

Answer (score 0):

`Map.copyOf(map)` is fully equivalent to `Collections.unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<>(map))`.

Neither does any kind of deep copying.  But it's strictly shorter to do `Maps.copyOf(map)`.

Comment: The difference appears if you later add items to source map - new added items appear in unmodifiableMap, but not in copyOf